# How to preserve a state value in React after call to another page

Tags: reactjs, parameter-passing, state

I have a simple React/Spring boot app where I'd like to pass a search string to a detail page, then link back to the parent using the same searchString as a parameter.

At that point, the parent page should take the value and store it back in the state.

As far as the existing code, when the parent opens, it sets a bunch of values in the state, including the search string:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const {cookies} = props;
    this.state = {
      word: '',
      newWord: '',
      searchString: '',
      licenses: [],
      licensePage: [],
      csrfToken: cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN'), 
      isLoading: true,
      licensesPerPage: 7,
      activePage: 1,
      begin: 0,
      end: 7
    };
```

The detail page (edit page) is called by pressing a button on the parent page:

```
<Button size="sm" color="primary" tag={Link} to={"/licenses/" + license.id}>Edit</Button>
```

The detail page returns to the parent by selecting either a "save" or "cancel" button:

```
<div>
    <Button color="primary" type="submit">Save</Button>{' '}
    <Button color="secondary" tag={Link} to="/licenses">Cancel</Button>
</div>
```

The submit is handled by an "onSubmit" function which calls "handleSubmit:

```
<Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
```

This is handleSubmit - only the last line is relevant here:

```
async handleSubmit(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    if(this.handleValidation()){
    } else {
      return;
    }

    const {item, csrfToken} = this.state;

    await fetch('/api/license' + (item.id ? '/' + item.id : '') , {
      method: (item.id) ? 'PUT' : 'POST',
      headers: {
        'X-XSRF-TOKEN': csrfToken,
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(item),
      credentials: 'include'
    });
    this.props.history.push('/licenses');
  }
```

It's the last line that I need to change:

```
this.props.history.push('/licenses');
```

should be:

```
this.props.history.push('/license/search/{searchString}');
```

I just need to populate searchString. I could then apply the same logic to the cancel.

So my question is, how to pass the searchString to the child, then grab it when it's passed to the parent in the URL?

======================= Attempt to implement answer failing on "not a fuction" error ==========

I tried the answer, but haven't been able to convert it to a class-based approach (I'm using classes, not function).

Here's the code. Note that I've temporarily added "2" to the variable names so it doesn't get confused with existing code.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Home from './Home';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import LicenseList from './LicenseList';
import LicenseEdit from './LicenseEdit';
import ImportList from './ImportList';
import { CookiesProvider } from 'react-cookie';

class App extends Component {

 state = {
    searchString2: ""
  };

  updateSearchString2 = (searchString2) => {
    this.setState({
      searchString2
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <CookiesProvider>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route path='/' exact={true} component={Home}/>
            <Route path='/licenses' exact={true} component={LicenseList}
                searchString2={this.state.searchString2} // props passed will be same value passed to DetailsPage
                updateSearchString2={this.updateSearchString2}
            />
            <Route path='/imports' exact={true} component={ImportList}/>
            <Route path='/licenses/:id' component={LicenseEdit}/>
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </CookiesProvider>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Relevant code in license list.js

```
  <div>
    <input type="text" value={this.props.searchString2} onChange={(e) =>  this.props.updateSearchString2(e.target.value)} />
```

This gives the error

```
TypeError: _this6.props.updateSearchString2 is not a function
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: In your question, you asked "how to pass the `searchString` to the child, then grab it when it's passed to the parent". Can you confirm if the detail page component is a child of the parent page component you've mentioned? Can you post your Routes as well?

Comment: I'm not at sure all it's a child, as this is my first React app and I am frankly just hacking my way through this. I've added the code in the question. Note that my strategy has changed from using the original "/licenses" specificid in the route to "/license/{searchString}". The idea is that if searchString is null, the API will return all licenses (as original "/licenses" does), but if the string contains something, it will return only matching licenses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have 1 source of truth for the `searchString` state such that, this state will be passed down as prop to both the "ParentPage" component and the "DetailsPage" component. For this, you can have a common parent component for both ParentPage & DetailsPage component

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    searchString: ""
  };

  updateSearchString = (searchString) => {
    this.setState({
      searchString
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Route
          exact
          path="/"
          render={() => (
            <ParentPage
              searchString={this.state.searchString} // props passed will be same value passed to DetailsPage
              updateSearchString={this.updateSearchString}
            />
          )}
        />
        <Route
          path="/license"
          render={() => <DetailsPage searchString={this.state.searchString} />}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In this scenario, regardless of any routing that occurred or any state changes, the `searchString` value will remain consistent all through out your components

[image: Edit frosty-wave-zkiiy]

For this requirement:

> The idea is that if searchString is null, the API will return all
> licences (as "/licenses" does), but if the string contains something,
> it will return only matching licenses.

since you already have access to the `searchString`, at this point you can have condition statements based on the `searchString` value and assess whether you need the API to return all licenses or not, etc

Comment: I'm having trouble converting this to a class-based implementation - I'm getting a "updateSearchString" is not a function. If you would like to take a look, I've posted the code in the body.

Comment: you can use the `render` prop instead of the `component` prop for your `<Route/>`. inside the `render` callback function, that is where you put your JSX along with the props. Example: `render={() => ( <LicenseList searchString2={this.state.searchString2} updateSearchString2={this.updateSearchString2} /> )}`

Comment: Thanks - that works! So just by changing "Component" to "render", it allows the function to be passed? Given that, is there any reason to ever use Component in the route command? Maybe because it's easier to read...I really have to pull it together and understand the differences between class-based and functional programming in React. With a backround in Java, obviously classes are easier and more intuitive, but functional programming seems to what React is about, at least based on the examples I see.

Comment: Technically the `component` can be used the same way. The main difference is, [as explained in the documentation](https://reactrouter.com/native/api/Route/component), using `component` will create new React elements to be rendered, this means that the old one will unmount and a totally new React element is rendered. Go ahead and test it in my CodeSandBox. Simply replace the `render` prop with the `component` prop. You will notice that typing in the input field (i.e., updating the state) will cause mounting of new element - so the orignal input is no longer in the DOM therefore `focus` is lost.